# SQL join on equal plus cartesian of those which not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to join two tables in such way that in the output I have an UNION of:

- INNER JOIN of matching records
- CARTESIAN of those which does not match (**excluding the records above, i.e. those that match**)
  Maybe this looks like a piece of cake, but I need to do it in an efficient way (for far more complex query than this below).

a: 1|2|3|5
b: 2|3|4|6

result: (2,2)|(3,3)|(1,4)|(1,6)|(5,4)|(5,6)

Any helpful tricks you could advise? (I work on SQL Server 2012)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a CTE to define the joined records, something like this:

```
WITH MatchedRows
AS
SELECT A.a, B.b FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON A.a = B.b

SELECT MatchedRows.a, MatchedRows.b
FROM MatchedRows
UNION
SELECT A.a, B.b FROM A a, B b
WHERE A.a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM MatchedRows)
  AND B.b NOT IN (SELECT b FROM MatchedRows)
```

Comment: That's the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the column names were, so just called them Col.

```
SELECT A.Col, 
B.Col 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
on A.Col = B.Col

UNION ALL

SELECT A.Col, 
B.Col 
FROM A 
CROSS JOIN B
WHERE A.Col NOT IN (SELECT B.Col FROM B)
AND B.Col NOT IN (SELECT A.Col FROM A)
```